# Docusaurus theme/Layout module cannot be found by Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, docusaurus

I am using Docusaurus to build a documentation site. In one of the react plugin page, I am using `import Layout from '@theme/Layout';` from https://docusaurus.io/docs/using-themes

However, the module cannot be picked up by Jest when I write tests for production.

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module '@theme/Layout' from 'src/pages/key-fields-filter.js'

    Require stack:
      src/pages/key-fields-filter.js
      src/pages/key-fields-filter.test.js

       98 | import clsx from 'clsx';
       99 | import styles from './key-fields-filter.module.css';
    > 100 | import Layout from '@theme/Layout';
          | ^
      101 | import useDocusaurusContext from '@docusaurus/useDocusaurusContext';
```

I have setup jest.config.js along with babel.config.js. According to the Docusaurus documentation, the @theme alias to the following path:
(Here I am using Layout.js not Navbar.js, but it should be the same.)

```
website
├── node_modules
│   └── docusaurus-theme
│       └── theme
│           └── Navbar.js
└── src
    └── theme
        └── Navbar.js
```

So, I set jest.config.js as the following:

```
moduleDirectories: [
    "node_modules",
    "node_modules/docusaurus-theme/theme",
    "src/theme"
  ],
```

But it still doesn't work. Anyone knows how Docusaurus works in this case? I tried to manually link the Layout.js from node_modules, but I couldn't find it. I am not even sure how Docusaurus links it in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just mock Layout using an empty component since Layout is from docusaurus which doesn't need tests for my project.

In jest.config.js

```
moduleNameMapper: {
    ...,
    '@theme/Layout': '<rootDir>/tests/layout-mock.js'
  },
```

In layout-mock.js

```
import React from 'react';
export default function Layout(props) {
    return (
        <div>{props.children}</div>
    )
}
```