# Docusaurus: Cannot find module "@docusaurus/router" when running Jest

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library, react-scripts, docusaurus

I am trying to setup unit tests for our Docusaurus instance. I am unable to load any of the Docusaurus modules during testing. Another user had the [same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69815033/docusaurus-theme-layout-module-cannot-be-found-by-jest) and his fix does allow me to get past the `@theme/Layout` error.

However, I am also getting the error when I try to test any components that use `@docusaurus/router`. I am using the router in my code for some page redirects so I need to be able to interact with in my tests.

I'm sure its something I'm doing wrong with how I setup Jest. I suspect me using `react-scripts` is probably what's causing thing to go crab.

I am able to replicate this using these steps:

```
npx create-docusaurus@latest unit-tests classic --typescript
yarn add @testing-library/react @types/jest jest react-scripts react-dom --dev
```

Adding a test script to the `package.json`.

```
  "scripts": {
    "docusaurus": "docusaurus",
    "start": "docusaurus start",
    "build": "docusaurus build",
    "swizzle": "docusaurus swizzle",
    "deploy": "docusaurus deploy",
    "clear": "docusaurus clear",
    "serve": "docusaurus serve",
    "write-translations": "docusaurus write-translations",
    "write-heading-ids": "docusaurus write-heading-ids",
    "typecheck": "tsc",
    "test": "react-scripts test"
  },
```

Then adding a simple unit test:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import Home from './index';

describe('<index>', () => {
    it('should', () => {
        render(<Home />);
    });
});
```

Here's my entire `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "unit-tests",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "docusaurus": "docusaurus",
    "start": "docusaurus start",
    "build": "docusaurus build",
    "swizzle": "docusaurus swizzle",
    "deploy": "docusaurus deploy",
    "clear": "docusaurus clear",
    "serve": "docusaurus serve",
    "write-translations": "docusaurus write-translations",
    "write-heading-ids": "docusaurus write-heading-ids",
    "typecheck": "tsc",
    "test": "react-scripts test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@docusaurus/core": "2.0.0-beta.18",
    "@docusaurus/preset-classic": "2.0.0-beta.18",
    "@mdx-js/react": "^1.6.22",
    "clsx": "^1.1.1",
    "prism-react-renderer": "^1.3.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@docusaurus/module-type-aliases": "2.0.0-beta.18",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
    "@tsconfig/docusaurus": "^1.0.5",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "jest": "^27.5.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "coverageReporters": [
      "json",
      "text",
      "lcov"
    ],
    "resetMocks": false
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.5%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Edit**
Its not `react-scripts`. I changed the yarn script to be just `"test": "jest"` and I get this error now:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    src/pages/index.tsx:3:20 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@theme/Layout' or its corresponding type declarations.

    3 import Layout from '@theme/Layout';
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    src/pages/index.tsx:4:18 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@docusaurus/Link' or its corresponding type declarations.

    4 import Link from '@docusaurus/Link';
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    src/pages/index.tsx:5:34 - error TS2307: Cannot find module '@docusaurus/useDocusaurusContext' or its corresponding type declarations.

    5 import useDocusaurusContext from '@docusaurus/useDocusaurusContext';
                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    src/pages/index.tsx:6:20 - error TS2307: Cannot find module './index.module.css' or its corresponding type declarations.

    6 import styles from './index.module.css';
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a hint in the Docusaurus Jest configs.
Using the `moduleNameMapper` we can map any module to any file, so I created a `mockUseDocusarusContext` in my project.

In the mock, you can import your actual config and provide it.
Although I ran into problems when trying to render elements that require the actual context, so I ended up using a shallow render in the test case for the index page.

There's probably a way to transform the imports or some other jest config to make it work correctly.

```
// /jest/mockUseDocusarusContext.ts
import config from "../docusaurus.config.js";

export default function mockDocusaurusContext() {
  return {
    siteConfig: config,
  };
}
```

```
// /jest.config.ts
export default {
//<other props>
moduleNameMapper: {
    // Jest can't resolve CSS or asset imports
    '^.+\\.(css|jpe?g|png|svg|webp)$': '<rootDir>/jest/emptyModule.ts',

    '@docusaurus/(use.*)':
    '<rootDir>/jest/mockUseDocusarusContext.ts',

    '@docusaurus/(BrowserOnly|ComponentCreator|constants|ExecutionEnvironment|Head|Interpolate|isInternalUrl|Link|Noop|renderRoutes|router|Translate)':
      '@docusaurus/core/lib',
    '@generated/.*': '<rootDir>/jest/emptyModule.ts',
    '@theme/(.*)': '@docusaurus/theme-classic/lib',
    '@site/(.*)': '<rootDir>/$1',
  },
}
```

```
// /src/pages/__tests__/index.test.tsx
import { expect, test } from "@jest/globals";
import React from "react";
import ShallowRenderer from "react-test-renderer/shallow";
import HomepageFeatures from "../../components/HomepageFeatures";
import Index, { HomepageHeader } from "../index";

const renderer = new ShallowRenderer();

test("changes the class when hovered", () => {
  const component = renderer.render(<Index />);
  const result = renderer.getRenderOutput();

  expect(result.props.children).toEqual([
    <HomepageHeader />,
    <main>
      <HomepageFeatures />
    </main>,
  ]);
});
```